# The form of a Riccati Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is a differential equation of the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=A(x)y^2+B(x)y+C(x)$$
Is this still a Riccati equation if A(x), B(x), C(x) are all constants rather than functions of the independent variable, x?

Comment: Yes, but I would say that it is basically a separable equation if A,B,C are constants.

Comment: Constants are still functions of $x$, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=Ay^2+By+C$ is still a Riccatti equation, if $A,B$ and $C$ are constants.